# Sort ClassA based on List of ClassB that is property of ClassA

Tags: java, sorting

Consider these classes:

```
public ClassA
{
    private String attr;
    private List<ClassB> classesB;
}

public ClassB
{
    private String attr1;
    private int attr2;
}
```

How can I sort/order a `List<ClassA>` based on `attr2`?

Consider that both classes have setters and getters.

Example: I have a list of `ClassA` where it contains 3 instances.

1 - `ClassA[0].getClassesB.get(n).attr2` has a value of 3;

2 - `ClassA[1].getClassesB.get(n).attr2` has a value of 1;

3 - `ClassA[2].getClassesB.get(n).attr2` has a value of 5;

where `n` is any number between 0 and `ClassA.getClassesB().size()`.

The expected result should be a list that has `ClassA[2]`, `ClassA[0]` and `ClassA[1]`, respectively.

Comment: Please explain exactly how you want the ordering to work. What value is to be used for n?

Comment: n is just a number to represent a given index in the list of classesB of ClassA.

Comment: A custom sort with a Comparator would do the trick, maybe something a little like this, just modify it to suit your needs: `Collections.sort(...)` would do the trick: `Collections.sort(listOfClassA, (ClassA o1, ClassA o2) -> { if(o1.getClassesB(n).attr2 > o2.getClassesB(0).attr2) return -1; else if (o1.getClassesB(n).attr2 == o2.getClassesB(0).attr2) return 0;  else return -1; });` See the last section of this tutorial on Comparators for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: But given that each ClassA instance has any number from 0 upwards of ClassB instances, how do you decide what value to use in the sort?

Answer (score 1):

Following sample code might work in your context:

```
public class CustomSortExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ClassA> inputList = Arrays.asList(
        new ClassA("ClassA[0]", Arrays.asList(new ClassB("ClassB[0]",3), new ClassB("ClassB[1]",9))),
        new ClassA("ClassA[1]", Arrays.asList(new ClassB("ClassB[0]",1), new ClassB("ClassB[1]",6))),
        new ClassA("ClassA[2]", Arrays.asList(new ClassB("ClassB[0]",5), new ClassB("ClassB[1]",4))));

    System.out.println(sortByAttr2OfClassB(inputList,0));
    System.out.println(sortByAttr2OfClassB(inputList,1));
  }

  private static List<ClassA> sortByAttr2OfClassB(List<ClassA> classAList, int n) {
    return classAList
        .stream()
        .sorted(
            (a , b) -> Integer.compare(b.getClassesB().get(n).getAttr2(), a.getClassesB().get(n).getAttr2())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}

class ClassA
{
  private String attr;
  private List<ClassB> classesB;

  public ClassA(final String attr, final List<ClassB> classesB) {
    this.attr = attr;
    this.classesB = classesB;
  }

  public List<ClassB> getClassesB() {
    return classesB;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return attr;
  }
}

class ClassB
{
  private String attr1;
  private int attr2;

  public ClassB(final String attr1, final int attr2) {
    this.attr1 = attr1;
    this.attr2 = attr2;
  }

  public int getAttr2() {
    return attr2;
  }
}
```